# ionic tabs and side menu navigation issue with subfolders

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am using a great template for ionic tabs and side menu as having issues with the navigation from the tabs. But when I use the code pen example and structure the html files into a templates folder and update the app.js file I lose the navigation.  I obviously do not understand the js link format correctly.  Please could someone explain it to me.

[My code pen is here](http://codepen.io/TizBooYah/pen/wWkayo)
[The original is here](http://codepen.io/calendee/pen/JdtuG?editors=1011)

app.js (each html file is in www/templates

```
angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic'])

.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    $stateProvider
        .state('entry', {
            url: '/entry/templates',
            templateUrl: 'templates/entry.html',
            controller: 'EntryPageController'
        })

        .state('main', {
            url: '/main/templates',
            templateUrl: 'templates/mainContainer.html',
            abstract: true,
            controller: 'MainController'
        })

        .state('main.home', {
            url: '/home',
            views: {
                'main': {
                    templateUrl: 'templates/home.html',
                    controller: 'HomePageController'
                }
            }
        })

        .state('main.info', {
            url: '/info',
            views: {
                'main': {
                    templateUrl: 'templates/info.html',
                    controller: 'InfoPageController'
                }
            }
        })

        .state('main.tabs', {
            url: '/tabs',
            views: {
                'main': {
                    templateUrl: 'templates/tabs.html',
                    controller: 'TabsPageController'
                }
            }
        })

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/entry');
}])

.controller('MainController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.toggleMenu = function () {
        $scope.sideMenuController.toggleLeft();
    }
}])

.controller('EntryPageController', ['$scope', '$state', function ($scope, $state) {
    $scope.navTitle = 'Entry Page';

    $scope.signIn = function () {
        $state.go('main.home');
    }
}])

.controller('HomePageController', ['$scope', '$state', function ($scope, $state) {
    $scope.navTitle = 'Home Page';

    $scope.leftButtons = [{
        type: 'button-icon icon ion-navicon',
        tap: function (e) {
            $scope.toggleMenu();
        }
    }];
}])

.controller('InfoPageController', ['$scope', '$state', function ($scope, $state) {
    $scope.navTitle = 'Info Page';

    $scope.leftButtons = [{
        type: 'button-icon icon ion-navicon',
        tap: function (e) {
            $scope.toggleMenu();
        }
    }];
}])

.controller('TabsPageController', ['$scope', '$state', function ($scope, $state) {
    $scope.navTitle = 'Tab Page';

    $scope.leftButtons = [{
        type: 'button-icon icon ion-navicon',
        tap: function (e) {
            $scope.toggleMenu();
        }
    }];
}])

enter code here
```

Comment: I am not sure to understand well your issue. I look at the your codepen, I see `templateUrl: 'templates/home.html',` it is normal that it's not working in the codepen. The files are not in `templates` folder. What you should is putting each html file in a templates folder if you want to put it there.

Comment: Hi as a beginner i use examples and modify to learn i think my issue was not creating ionic views i  new html files.